# Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu on the new Lenovo miix 700 and haven't been able to get the wireless working. I used to have to remove and blacklist the `ideapad_laptop` wireless driver/controller with `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and `/etc/.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf` to on the previous Lenovo miix model but didn't have luck doing that with this problem.

Kernel Version 3.19.0-25-generic

`lshw -C network`:

```
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d1500000-d1501fff
```

When I run `ifconfig` I don't get a wireless link

```
[    2.413997] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.415741] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415753] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415761] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415770] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415779] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415785] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.415787] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-8000C-12.ucode' failed.
[    2.415790] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

`lspci -nn | grep 8086`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
```

The problem was a lot like what was found in this post so I followed [these steps](/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network).

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version, kernel version? You need to install firmware.

Comment: If you mean apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree I just did that, but I still don't have a driver showing up configured under lshw -c network, or a wireless network

Comment: Please answer the first question. It is nit about `linux-firmware-nonfree`, but about `linux-firmware`. You will need to update it depending on which verion is installed.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/729212/install-intel-ac-8260-wireless-drivers-offline

Comment: Ubuntu 17-10, the drivers are extremely unstable but those are whats installed

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, you need to connect to internet by wire or a USB adapter and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

This will install kernel 4.2 that supports this adapter and will update the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Your system cannot find the firmware for your wireless adapter. `apt-file search -x 'iwlwifi-8000C-.*\.ucode'` returns:

```
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
```

The most likely solution to your issue seems to be to install that package, if you can find another method to connect your computer to the internet:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Otherwise you can [perform an offline installation](/q/974/175814).

Then you need to reload the wireless driver module or reboot the computer.

Edit: This only works on Trusty (with the [`trusty-updates` repository enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nZoX.png)).

For  Wily and the upcoming Xenial the adapter will work out-of the-box.

Comment: It depends on which Ubuntu version is installed. But OP does not tell us. I suspect OP has a non-ubuntu distro.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: This won't work e.g. on 14.04.

Comment: @Pilot6: I ran the command on 14.04.3. According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi-8000C&mode=filename&suite=trusty-updates&arch=any the file is included in `trusty-updates`. I'll make a note in my question about that.

Comment: Firstly OP does not have any internet connection. And 3.19 kernel will not load firmware 13

Comment: @Pilot6: According to the question, the kernel is looking for, amongst others, `iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode`, but I'm not intimate with the firmware loading process. I would like to keep the question until OP reveals more information about their system. In the mean time I'll refer to instructions on how to install packages without internet connection.

Comment: I see the point. This means that it is not an Ubuntu 3.19 kernel. It knows only 12 version of firmware.

Comment: For wily and xenial there is no need to install anything. They have the correct module and firmware.