# Install Intel AC 8260 wireless drivers offline

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

As my laptop does not have Ethernet port, to set up wireless, I need to install drivers offline.

My Ubuntu version is 14.04.3, and kernel version is 3.19.0-25-generic.

Output of the command:
 `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:`

is:

```
 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
```

Since here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305426

it is suggested to try following these steps:

[Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network)

I tried, but without any success.

Now I am not sure what to try next. I am not Ubuntu expert, and would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is not clear. Do you have an Intel or a Broadcom adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: First of all connect to internet by wire and update you system.

Comment: Yes, thanks!! It's Intel actually. Sorry, I was a bit confused. There is no Ethernet port on the laptop which causes the problem. So, I have to do it offline. Hopefully, that would be possible? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Is the system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It is a 64 bit.

Comment: OK. I will add directions to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that kernel 3.19 does not support firmware version 13 that you can get for Ubuntu 14.04.

The easiest way to do offline is to install Ubuntu 15.10.

The adapter should work without any effort.

You can get it working on Ubuntu 14.04, but you will need to upgrade the kernel and the firmware. I can give you directions.

But you will have to download some packages using another computer and then install them to Ubuntu.

## Install to Ubuntu 14.04

Download these files:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-wily/linux-headers-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.42.34_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-wily/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic_4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-wily/linux-headers-4.2.0-42_4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-wily/linux-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.42.34_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-wily/linux-image-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.42.34_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-wily/linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic_4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-wily/linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic_4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1_amd64.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.127.22_all.deb
```

Copy the files to your home folder and run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and test the Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot!! I would like to stay with 14.04. Could you please send me directions? Thanks!

Comment: Is the system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: it is 64 bit system.

Comment: You are great!!! It works!!! Thanks so much!!!!!!

Comment: You can also remove 3.19 linux-image and headers using synaptic.

Comment: Hm,  I think I would rather leave it if it will not interfere with anything in future. Except, you strongly recommend I remove them?

Comment: Links get 404...

Comment: @Almaron This is outdated. Now kernel an firmware packages have newer versions.

Comment: I fixed the links.