# wlan0 disappeared after update for intel 8260 - help me recover?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm running a relatively new Dell XPS with 14.04 LTS.  Everything had been working fine and I've done several updates.  Last night I used the Software Updater and installed a number of updates, after which I could not connect to any wifi networks.

When I run ifconfig, it returns only lo and eth1.  Previously, it would also have returned wlan0.

I've also run:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Which returns:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
```

I can connect via ethernet, but really need to get the wifi up and running again.

This answers seems to suggest an offline solution: [Install Intel AC 8260 wireless drivers offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729212/install-intel-ac-8260-wireless-drivers-offline)

But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient solution while I'm connected via ethernet?

EDIT/UPDATE:

Per @Pilot6 request, I'm adding the output of `dkms status` below:

```
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260, 1.7, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
intel-hid, 2.0, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid, 0.201512022217~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rts-cr, 1.4.3oem2, 3.19.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
synaptic-i2c-hid-3.13.0-32-backport, 1.6.4: added
```

Comment: There was a case where disabling secure boot helped for iwlwifi too, but I can't get the reason.

Comment: Please tell us the result of this terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` If you get "Required key not available" then @Pilot6 is quite correct. Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @chili555 Do you have any idea why an in-tree module may require Secure boot disabled?

Comment: @chili555:  the result of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` is `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Required key not available`  - sorry - meant to add that I'm about to try the suggestion...

Comment: @chili555 this may betray my ignorance, but I can't figure out how to disable secure boot.  All my (admittedly quick) research yields two options:  first is to do it via BIOS (not sure how to do that) and the second is to follow these two commands:  `sudo apt install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation`  -- which do you recommend?  And thanks already for your help/guidance.

Comment: @Pilot6 I do not, however, the issue with iwlwifi has come up a few times in the past ten days or so; I think it is a new problem.

Comment: @outsideshot The easiest way is to disable it in bios. With the command it is more complicated and it depends on bios.

Comment: I suggest you do so in the BIOS. As you boot the computer, it should have a way to enter the setup utility, also known as BIOS. Look around until you find something similar to this: http://www.top-password.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/disable-secure-boot.jpg Select 'Disable' and boot into Ubuntu and you should be all set.

Comment: @chili555 - I made the change in BIOS and it worked.  The NIC is back.  How can I credit you for the great answer and guidance?  I really appreciate it and will try to pay it forward.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I also thank you.  I would be happy to tick the box on your answer, but concerned that the answer below is different from the actual resolution that we discussed in the comments section.

Comment: I will write an answer. Thanks for your kind words.

Comment: @outsideshot That is not a problem. Now we have an two answers. One how to fix your  problem and one how to update the kernel. My solution may work with Secure Boot on.

Comment: @outsideshot Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I've run the command and made the edit above.   Does that reveal anything interesting?

Comment: It does. You've installed a custom module. I will update my answer. Please test if it works.

Comment: And it looks that you installed many DKMS custom modules, that do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Required key not
>   available

This is a new issue in Ubuntu. I suggest that you register and file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

It appears that the only solution so far is to enter the computer's BIOS and turn off Secure Boot.

To do so, look around the options after booting your computer in the setup utility mode; look for a Secure Boot switch and turn it off. Then exit and boot Ubuntu normally

Secure Boot is a security standard developed by the PC industry to help make sure that your PC boots using only software that is trusted by the PC manufacturer

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I have a 7260 AC adapter with Secure Boot enabled and I do not have this problem on Xenial.

Comment: @Pilot6 It seems that somebody made a dkms package from backports to support some newer Intel chipsets, it is named btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260.  A few users on ubuntuforums must have used it for a 8260 chipset with a subsystem ID of 0050

Comment: That makes sense. We need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the kernel and firmware by one command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-firmware
```

if you are connected to internet.

Besides that you need to update the kernel to support Intel 8260 adapter, you need to remove a custom `btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260` module that you installed to support 8260 on older kernels.

Remove it by

```
sudo dkms remove btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260/1.7 --all
```

With installed the 4.4 (xenial) kernel the Intel 8260 should work out of the box with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: Am I correct that this will only be effective if I upgrade my kernel to 4.4?  Currently I'm running 3.19 (per `uname -a` which returns `3.19.0-65-generic #73~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 21:05:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: You installed a custom kernel module that supports the 8260 adapter on kernel 3.19. That is why you need to disable Secure Boot. Kernel 4.4 supports this adapter natively.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - I'm hesitant to upgrade my kernel now that everything seems to be working and stable.   But I really appreciate the suggestion.  I'm going to do a little more research on this front but I will upvote your answer anyway.