# Anyone using Ubuntu on Lenovo Miix 700?

Tags: lenovo

Considering buying one, but would love to hear what works and what does not. And, yes, I tried google, but the only thing I could find was this [Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728874/intel-corporation-wireless-8260-808624f3-rev-3a)

Comment: I also would like to know. This is the best specked 2in1 available in my country that remotely looks Linux compatible. Here is a post from a French user that looks very promising. https://www.google.co.jp/url?q=http://www.tablette-tactile.net/test/lenovo-miix-700-175399/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj2tdPlkPzPAhUMjJQKHdgQBugQFggXMAQ&sig2=8MiHRhup6bGyxzZooA1Bcw&usg=AFQjCNHU3r4BLhl0WM01iIWIICh7GEFeHQ

Comment: Here is an article from another French user. http://www.jolegeek.fr/2016/06/ubuntu-1604-les-astuces-pour-economiser.html?m=1 it seems that everyone has been pleased with the performance of the device on Linux

Comment: Can we get any verification on whether this works as 'out of the box' as the post mentions? I'm also curious about this.

Answer (score 3):

Got Ubuntu 16.04 installed as dual-boot with Windows 10 and it's working fine, well more or less...

Depending on the Ubuntu Variants, you may have to disable/tweak UEFI options in your bios.

Depending also on the Ubuntu variants, you may have full native resolution/definition so the display might be very tiny and when I said tiny, it's really really tiny... ^^

With standard Ubuntu, looks like (double) hiDPI is activated and so icons and characters are much bigger.

As described by others "basic" functions are working or should work : wireless and bluetooth are working fine (may or may not need some firmwares to download).

Depending on the resolution/definition you're using, you have to play with touchscreen calibration.

Most native functions can be controlled from the keyboard such as : dimmable display, sounds controls, etc...

To install and configure the Intel Realsense drivers, it's a real pain as it needs many pre-requisites and using the back Intel Realsense camera is still another story as you need specific softwares to fully use it (with Ubuntu 16.04.2 looks like Intel Realsense drivers are pre-installed)...

As it was not my priority, I did a quick and dirty install and hack so I could use it with guvcview... more or less... ^^

I was able to view through the back camera, record videos with it but I was unable to play the recorded videos back as we only have "a still video" and with sound... ^^

You need specific softwares to use the Intel 3D Realsense camera.

It is not usable with Cheese and with VLC, it's just so weird I can't explain the result...

This part has been edited as I made a mistake about the OV5670 driver and I think the real reference is (Intel ?) AVStream 2500 camera but no way to find any source code anywhere, nor from Intel or from Microsoft, and of course nothing from Lenovo ! :(

I don't have the Lenovo Wacom Pen so I can tell much about it but I saw on Youtube some other persons said it it working fine, except pressure controls.

I now have the Lenovo Wacom pen and I confirm what was said : working out of the box but no pressure controls yet.
For display rotation/autorotation it is not functional but should be with some hacks and scripts.

If you want to use it as a basic touch laptop it's fine, but if you want a full touch tablet there are SOME hard works to do !

As soon as I could get the front camera working I will update this thread. ;)

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do all of these things. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: @Arobase You may want [to get your two accounts merged](https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts).