# Three identical WiFi cards but Linux driver only loads reliably for one of them?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, iwlwifi

#### Related Questions

I will prelude this question with the links to the other questions:

1.) [Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728874/intel-corporation-wireless-8260-808624f3-rev-3a) ( I tried this but unfortunately no luck. They never had a wireless card show up.)

2.) [Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network?noredirect=1&lq=1) ( Similar issue but again does not work) Both of these posts are older before Intel released the drivers for this wifi card.

#### My Question

I have three Intel wifi cards plugged into my computer via PCIe. However, between boots they only create wireless interfaces for the cards randomly. Sometimes 1 card shows up... Sometimes all 3 cards show up.

If I run lspci. I see

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
0c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a5 (rev 03)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

If I run ifconfig I see

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:88:88:88:87:88  
      inet addr:192.168.241.224  Bcast:192.168.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c18e:2bc3:5517:78e6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:271252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:31020563 (31.0 MB)  TX bytes:468963 (468.9 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:b1700000-b1720000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:15605 (15.6 KB)  TX bytes:15605 (15.6 KB)

wlp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:34:d9:ee:3b:99  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So I am trying to figure out where the other two wifi cards went. Following some other posts I tried running lshw -C network.

The output is as follows.

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 3a
   serial: a4:34:d9:ee:3b:99
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:339 memory:b1500000-b1501fff
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:340 memory:b1400000-b1401fff
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:341 memory:b1200000-b1201fff
```

The interesting thing is that one of the wifi cards reports the correct capabilities to announce itself as a network device but the other two for some reason are not working. Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working??

Uname -a

```
Linux cirrus 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ls /lib/firmware | grep iwlwifi

```
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
```

Comment: I'll ask an obvious question... why would you install 3 wireless cards into the same machine at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody else comes across a similar issue. There are three main causes for this.

1. Bad drivers
2. Bad firmware
3. Bad hardware

Ours came from bad hardware where the pcie power bring up time was too slow for the wifi cards.