# No Wifi Adapter Found - Dell XPS 13 9350 (2016) after upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, dell

Sorry if this has been posted before, I searched previous questions but didn't find one that fit my specific issue and laptop model.

As the title says I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and now the wifi icon at the top doesn't show up and when I search Wi-Fi settings I get "No Wi-Fi adapter found"

I have access to a USB to ethernet adapter if I need to download any drivers or install updates and have already disabled secure boot in the BIOS options.

I ran `lspci` and my network controller is **Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)**

`uname` says my kernel version is **5.4.0-1035-gke**

Let me know if I should gather any further info or if I should just replace my wireless card, and if so which one is the best replacement.

Thanks!

Edit: my ethernet adapter isn't working either so I don't currently have internet access on the laptop. In order to get the ethernet working I had to boot into a different kernel available to me on restart (5.4.0-65-generic)

Output from `sudo lshw -c network` with kernel **5.4.0-1035-gke**:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Network controller 
product: Wireless 8260 
vendor: Intel Corporation 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0 
version: 3a 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list 
configuration: latency=0 
resources: memory:dc200000-dc201fff
```

Output from `sudo lshw -c network` with kernel **5.4.0-65-generic**:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:a7:a0:8f:85:68
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.2.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:136 memory:dc200000-dc201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: enx000ec6bd7ad0
       serial: 00:0e:c6:bd:7a:d0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a duplex=full ip=192.168.2.106 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

No additional drivers are available in the software and updates center

Edit2: My wireless card also seems to be working now that I'm using the older kernel, should I continue booting into this kernel then and that solves my issue? Are there any issues with doing this and will future updates create more problems?

Comment: Can you run `sudo lshw -c network` and check what shows up under wireless interface? Also check that you have the correct drivers installed using the software & updates center under the tab "additional drivers" -- Edit: It looks like the correct drivers are not installed. I found the following post which might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/728874/intel-corporation-wireless-8260-808624f3-rev-3a.

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1035-gke` then reboot and try that kernel

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a dual boot system with Windows the fast boot mechanism of Windows may cause problems. Thus, turn it off in Windows as explained in this post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/456355) and the issue may go away. At least my Thinkpad L480 running Debian Bullseye accepted the solution.